# Independence of random of random variables and triangle inequality

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. I have the events $A = \left[\omega:\ |X-x|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right]$ and $B = \left[\omega:\ |Y-y|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right]$. I am wondering if $P(A\cap B) \leq P(|(X+Y)-(x+y)|<\varepsilon)  \leq P(|X-x|+|Y-y|<\varepsilon)$, but I am not quite sure why this is true. At first I thought that

$P(A\cap B)=P(|X-x|+|Y-y|<\varepsilon)$ but the event of the right hand side seems bigger.

I'll appreciate some guidence.

Comment: If $E_1$ implies $E_2$, then $P(E_1)\leq P(E_2)$. Or in set theoretic language, $E_1\subset E_2$.

Comment: The event $A\cap B$ is not exactly $|X-x|+|Y-y|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's address your second question first. $|X - x| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $|Y - y| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ imply $|X - x| + |Y - y| < \varepsilon$ but the reverse is not necessarily true: for instance you can have a scenario where $|X - x| < \frac{3\varepsilon}{4}$ and $|Y - y| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$ to get the same result. Hence you only get $A \cap B \subseteq \{|X - x| + |Y - y| < \varepsilon\}$ in general.

Now $P(A\cap B) \leq P(|(X+Y)-(x+y)|<\varepsilon)  \leq P(|X-x|+|Y-y|<\varepsilon)$ is not true because the second inequality should be reversed i.e. it should be
$$
P(A\cap B) \leq P(|X-x|+|Y-y|<\varepsilon) \leq P(|(X+Y)-(x+y)|<\varepsilon)
$$ The first inequality is from $A \cap B \subseteq \{|X - x| + |Y - y| < \varepsilon\}$ and the second inequality is because if $|X-x|+|Y-y|<\varepsilon$, then via the triangle inequality
$$
|(X + Y) - (x + y)| \leq |X-x|+|Y-y|<\varepsilon
$$ i.e. $\{|X-x|+|Y-y|<\varepsilon\} \subseteq \{|(X + Y)-(x + y)|<\varepsilon\}$.

Comment: Thank you @0XLR, now I see i made a typo. It should be $|(X+Y)−(x+y)|$ instead of $|(X−Y)−(x+y)|$ in my question

Comment: @Mangostino I also had a typo since I copied off your question. Fixed it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This kind of problem I have a hard time seeing the solution sometimes. But now I understand the reasoning.